# Is it possible to get a YouTube access token to upload without going through a browser?

Tags: youtube-data-api

I'm trying to make a script that uploads videos to Youtube every week using python, Docker, AWS ECS Fargate and [Youtube API v3 insert](https://developers.google.com/youtube/v3/docs/videos/insert).

It works locally but I have to manually click on buttons on a form in a browser to upload the video to YouTube due to OAuth2.

This won't work in a Docker Container. Is it possible to get an indefinite token to upload videos? Or else use an API key instead to authenticate the video? or is there another way to get the -oauth2.json file without going through a browser?

Thanks in advance for any help.